# the meaning of #! in python separately

Tags: python

I could add #! /usr/bin/python in the beginning of python script and add this script to PATH in order to run it as a command.

But could anyone explain to me what does '#' and '!' mean separately in python and what other language has this mechanism?
Thanks

Comment: please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line and the #! are [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Magic_number) interpreted by the program loader on unix systems and used to start the script interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

`#` followed by anything is a comment; so far as Python itself is concerned, that's it.  Unix, on the other hand, will parse out the `/usr/bin/python` so that it knows how to run your code.